# How to groupby the values in one dataframe based on a condition in another dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two dataframes whose values are correlated. The first one, let's call DF, has some values plues each recording number, like this:

```
                   ts  pou     X     Y  value   recording_number
0  1/1/12 12:15:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.37       4089
1  1/1/12 12:30:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.42       4089
2  1/1/12 12:45:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.32       4089
3   1/1/12 1:00:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.36       4089
4   1/1/12 1:15:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.33       4089
5   1/1/12 1:30:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.40       4089
6   1/1/12 1:45:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.38       4089
7   1/1/12 2:00:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.43       4089
8   1/1/12 2:15:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.35       4089
9   1/1/12 2:30:00 AM  NaN     1     3  -0.38       4089
```

DF is pretty long so that the recording_number is gonna change many times.
The second dataframe, let's call it 'Table', has the recording numbers, as well, plus an id_number.

```
 id_number  recording_number
0         167      9206
1         167      9824
2         167     10890
3         167     10895
4         167     10942
5         167     10944
6         167     11244
7         167     11249
8         167     11567
9         167     11568
```

Many recording numbers belong to the same id_number.

I would like to groupby all the data in DF belonging to the same id_number in Table. i.e. to groupby all the data with a specific recording_number in DF which have the same id_number in Table.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `df.merge(table)` ? It would help if you can comeup with a [mcve].

Comment: @harvpan I've already tried it, but as the dataframes are too long and it ends up lika a mess.  I am looking for something like `DF.groupby['recording_number'].filter(lambda x: x something)` where x would refer to Table.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```py
df_test = DF.merge(Table, how='inner', right_on='recording_number', left_on='recording_number')

df_test.groupby(by=['recording_number', 'id_number'])
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a little error in my description. There is not "recording_id" but only "recording_number".

Comment: But what `aggfunc` do you want to apply on the group by ?